# Bootstrap - how to clear css from element to start over?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap to build my design, but it is too rigid.
I want to clear the defaults and override the styling for a specific element.
In other words, I want to style my `active` class from scratch making use of defaults of JavaScript, without overriding every single style on that element.
How can I do that?

Comment: Open up the style sheet, find what you need to replace. Make a new style sheet and code it how you like and place it after the bootstrap.css file in the `<head>` so that it can override any default property you dont wanna use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either directly edit your stylesheet, or better, create a new stylesheet and call it something like custom.css, and link to it from your header.

Then you can proceed to add classes to that stylesheet, and as long as it is loaded after bootstrap, the styles should override.

you can also use the built-in bootstrap customizing tool before downloading a package here: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

or you can use this tool: http://bootstrap-live-customizer.com/

of course these two tools would work if you're looking for something better looking but not necessary specific like a design comp, otherwise, a custom stylesheet as mentioned above is the best way to go.